# PHP and Oracle - Connection as SYS should be as SYSDBA or SYSOPER

Tags: php, oracle11g

I am getting the above error when trying to create my Master repository using an Oracle 11g database. 
I am entering SYS as the user, with the correct password and all. However, it is telling me SYS must connect as SYSDBA or SYSOPER. 
I went into my user management in the 11G, and made sure that SYS has SYSDBA and SYSOPER checked under the "priveleges" section. I keep getting the same error though. 
Any ideas?

```
<?php
$db = "(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 1.1.1.1)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)))" ;

if($c = OCILogon("sys", "your database password", $db))
{
    echo “Successfully connected to Oracle.\n”;
    OCILogoff($c);
}
else
{
    $err = OCIError();
    echo “Connection failed.” . $err[text];
}
?>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Try adding AS SYSDBA after the username inside the quotes (you can't connect to sys without specifying this role) although I don't think that it is possible to connect as sysdba so create another user and give it the DBA role and use that.